# Need a design advice to skip object type casting

Tags: java, oop, casting, polymorphism

I have a domain class which has a lot of children as shown below ( B is the interface type and B1 and B2 ) implementing the B interface.

As you can see in my main class it needs to cast the (B1 b1 = (B1) a.getB();) and we know it can be B1 or B2, so it should be alright for my knowledge.

Problem I have is the type can grow a lot, people who uses the A needs to put more conditions to check the instance of B and access the specific values of B1 or B2 … **is there any ways that I can skip this casting so it can reduce a lot of conditions in the future**

```
public class TestMain
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    A a = new A();
    //this can be B1 or B2 
    B1 b1 = (B1) a.getB();
  }
}

public class A
{
  private B b;

  protected B getB()
  {
    return b;
  }

  protected void setB(B b)
  {
    this.b = b;
  }
}

public interface B
{
  void test();
}

public class B1 implements B
{
  @Override
  public void test()
  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }
}
public class B2 implements B
{
  @Override
  public void test()
  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `instance of` keyword ?

Comment: Why do you need to cast your B instance to the specific sub-type (B1, B2, etc...)? The idea of having a common interface is to use only the methods of that interface. If in some cases you need to use methods unique to one of the implementing classes, you have to cast it (after checking its type with `instanceof`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you really need this feature (Eran's comment above raises a good point; polymorphism likely does much or all of what you need), the answer is generics. They're a slightly advanced topic, but they're central to Java (all of the collection classes in the JDK use them), so they're very important to learn.

Generics are a way to say "some type," and optionally "some type that's a subtype of some other type." The latter is what you want.

```
public class A<T extends B>
{
  private T b;

  protected T getB()
  {
    return b;
  }

  protected void setB(T b)
  {
    this.b = b;
  }
}
```

The `<T extends B>` part declares a generic parameter of `T`, and says it must be a subclass of `B`. From then on, you can use `T` as if it's a type within the `A` class. For users of this class, they'll have to specify what kind of `A` it is, and the compiler will automatically do the downcasting for you:

```
A<B1> a = new A<B1>();
a.set(new B1());
B1 b = a.getB();
```

Note that in the second line, if you had done `a.set(new B2())` it would be a compile-time error: the compiler would complain that `a` is parameterized to `B1`, and therefore you can't pass a `B2` to it. At a very high level, you can imagine that the compiler is doing a search-and-replace, replacing `T` in the original class with `B1`. And if you had declared:

```
A<B2> a = new A<B2>();
```

then the search-and-replace would similarly turn `T` into `B2`.

In reality, it's not quite that simple due to something called erasure. You can read more at the [Java trail on generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/), and there are lots of other resources available as well. [This PDF](http://www8.cs.umu.se/kurser/TDBB24/HT05/jem/download/generics-tutorial.pdf) is a good intermediate-level description.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do as below without casting.

```
B b1 = a.getB();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly add a cast when you perform down-casting. Up-casting is implicit and something which is always safe. Also, why do you need to explicitly cast it to B1 or B2. Instead **you can use it base interface type as reference to the object** (i.e B) which will not require you to add a cast.

Also it is safe to you base reference type as you need not worry about the actual object-type and thus **prevent ClassCastException at runtime.**

Using base type as reference to object has many advantages:

- Avoid ClassCastException at runtime.
- You need not worry about adding a cast
- Also if you add more classes to the base class hierarchy, you still can access these classes with the base reference type. This makes your design more flexible.

Comment: you are exactly correct in my case it is needed for the user to access the B1 or B2 specific values so in that case they need to cast it

Comment: If the answer is correct please go ahead and mark it as accepted. Here is the link you can refer for details. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B1();
        if(B1.class.getName().equals(b.getClass().getName())){
            // implement logic for B1 class
        }else if(B1.class.getName().equals(b.getClass().getName())){
            // implement logic for B2 class         
        }
    }
}

interface B{    
}

class B1 implements B{  
}

class B2 implements B{  
}
```

or

do method overriding and you can implement different logic for different class and you can call the methods using interface reference with out any casting

Comment: This if-else chain isn't great for various reasons, but if you did want to go about it, why compare class names? Why not just `if(B1.class.equals(b.getClass())...` ?